# How to properly build static binary of Tor on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: configuration, ubuntu

Is there a guide to build static version of Tor from latest source on Ubuntu 13.04?

I'm looking for ldd output: 
`not a dynamic executable`

There is main problem that I have remembered, openssl-dev doesn't contain static part, only shared version of libraries.

I have no problems on the OpenBSD, but Ubuntu. Am I must rebuild the whole backend by myself?

Comment: What is it you really want to do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library

Comment: This is still too obscure. If you wanted to tell your great grandmother about it... What is it you really want to do? This might be an [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: This is X, I'm only looking for way to build static binaries of Tor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building Tor statically is problematic, at best, and not really (well) supported.

I got configure to run with this minor patch:

```
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -542,7 +542,7 @@ AC_ARG_WITH(ssl-dir,
       fi
   ])

-TOR_SEARCH_LIBRARY(openssl, $tryssldir, [-lssl -lcrypto $TOR_LIB_GDI],
+TOR_SEARCH_LIBRARY(openssl, $tryssldir, [-lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl $TOR_LIB_GDI],
     [#include <openssl/rand.h>],
     [void RAND_add(const void *buf, int num, double entropy);],
     [RAND_add((void*)0,0,0); exit(0);], [],
```

And then running `autogen.sh` again.

This is, of course, some horribly monkey-patching without any concern for The Right Thing, but it made `configure` with `--enable-static-tor --with-libevent-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ --with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` run through.

The build then fails when trying to link `tor-gencert`, but it produced a static tor binary:

```
[git|master] weasel@valiant:~/projects/tor/tor/build-tree$ find -name tor
./src/or/tor                                               
[git|master] weasel@valiant:~/projects/tor/tor/build-tree$ file src/or/tor                                                                                                          
src/or/tor: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0xc35ac69bf7ed2d7c736daec2df91ef6367cc9e74, not stripped
[git|master] weasel@valiant:~/projects/tor/tor/build-tree$ ldd src/or/tor 
        not a dynamic executable
```

and lots of warnings during the build:

```
  CCLD   src/or/tor
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x19): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
src/common/libor.a(util.o): In function `check_private_dir':
util.c:(.text+0x4e83): warning: Using 'getgrgid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
src/or/libtor.a(connection.o): In function `connection_listener_new':
connection.c:(.text+0x3c76): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
src/or/libtor.a(control.o): In function `getinfo_helper_misc':
control.c:(.text+0x482b): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
src/common/libor.a(address.o): In function `tor_addr_lookup':
address.c:(.text+0x9ba): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent.a(evutil.o): In function `evutil_getaddrinfo_common':
(.text+0x14a7): warning: Using 'getprotobynumber' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

So, in short:  It can be done.  Maybe not a good idea.

Comment: Anyway, for flexibility it shall be realized. I'm talking about chrooting and speed, plus mobility.