# How to bundle completely portable version of Tor

Tags: configuration, linux

A friend and I are working on a project that includes Tor. It needs to be completely portable, including all libraries it needs. All I was able to find via research was building a static Tor binary, but 1. It was noted that this is very bad practice, and 2. when I try to , I get:

```
...
checking for event2/bufferevent_ssl.h... yes
checking for library containing pow... -lm  
checking for openssl directory... configure: WARNING: Could not find a linkable openssl.  If you have it installed somewhere unusual, you can specify an explicit path using --with-openssl-dir  
configure: WARNING: On Debian, you can install openssl using "apt-get install libssl-dev"    
configure: error: Missing libraries; unable to proceed.
root@K7DXS-Laptop:/var/git/tor#
```

Note that yes, I have installed libssl-dev using apt-get.

How do I either:

1. <strike>Successfully compile a static binary that could be used in production, or</strike>
2. Make the standard tor binary portable even on systems without the libraries (libevent, libssl, and zlib) without a static binary?

**EDIT:** I just realized that I'm using a 64-bit system, so when compiling I would get a 64-bit binary. I need a 32-bit one for portability.

Comment: If it wasn't already part of your research (I'm suspecting it probably was), have a look at this previous thread: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-to-properly-build-static-binary-of-tor-on-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: @RichardHorrocks That's exactly what I did. That is what says it's very bad practice, and those instructions give me this error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to link the binaries all-static **except** system libraries. I've tried to link it full-static, but the portability suffered greatly. That's how I ended with a portable build(for Raspberry Pi exactly) :

```
ldd /usr/tor/bin/tor
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0xb6cbe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6c2e000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb6bd5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb6a68000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcap.so.2 (0xb6a54000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6a2c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6a19000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0xb69f2000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb69c5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6888000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x7f59c000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libattr.so.1 (0xb6872000)
```